# Can I have multiple POSIX FIFOs in a single process?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, named-pipes, fifo

I am creating three FIFO pipes for a single process where multiple writer threads write to a single reader thread.  The goal is a separate file descriptor for each writer thread with a corresponding reader file descriptor for each writer file descriptor so that I know which writer thread belongs to each record.  My setup works fine with one writer file descriptor shared among all writer threads and a single reader file descriptor.

The multiple reader/writer setup works successfully to set up three writer fds (6, 7, 8) and three reader fds (9, 10 and 11).  All writer threads successfully send data, BUT the reader fds do not successfully read the data (return zero bytes read).

When I open the fd on the writer side, I get the error message "open: Bad file descriptor" but it still returns a unique fd, and that fd is used successfully to write, but not to read.

I call the C programs from NASM in a loop, one iteration for each writer thread:

```
xor r12,r12
mov r13,[Number_Of_Cores_Calc]
Setup_pipe:
lea rdi,[fifo_base_name]
mov rax,r12
add rax,48
mov byte[rdi+11],al
call fifo_delete wrt ..plt
call fifo_setup wrt ..plt
push rdi
call fifo_close wrt ..plt
pop rdi
Open_FIFO_Write:
mov rsi,1
call fifo_open wrt ..plt
lea rbp,[fifo_write_fds]
mov [rbp+r12*8],rax
add r12,1
cmp r12,r13
jl Setup_pipe
```

The corresponding C programs:

```
int64_t fifo_setup(char * fifo_name)
{

    remove(fifo_name);

    if (mkfifo(fifo_name, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH) == -1) {
        perror("mkfifo");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

        return 0;
}

int64_t fifo_open(char * fifo_name, int64_t read_write) {

    int c;

    if (read_write == 1) { 
        c = open(fifo_name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR);} //O_WRONLY
    if (read_write == 2) { 
        c = open(fifo_name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR);} //O_RDONLY

    perror("open");

    return (c);
}

int64_t fifo_read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count) {

    int status_read = read(fd, buf, count); 
    return status_read;
}

int64_t fifo_write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count) {

    int status_write = write(fd, buf, count);
    return status_write; }

int64_t fifo_close(int fifo_fdes) {

    close(fifo_fdes); 

    return 0; }

// Delete pre-existing file
int64_t fifo_delete(char * fifo_name) {

    if( access( fifo_name, F_OK ) != -1 ) {
        if (remove(fifo_name) == 0)
        printf("File deleted successfully"); 
    else
        printf("Unable to delete the file");
    }

    return 0; }
```

So my questions are:

1. Can I write from multiple threads to a single reader thread using separate fds for each thread on both the write and read sides?
2. If I can, what did I do wrong above -- especially why am I getting "open: Bad file descriptor" but I still get what looks like a valid file descriptor.
3. If I can't use POSIX FIFOs, what IPC methods can I use so each writer thread has its own unique fd on both writer and reader sides?  Datagram sockets?

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: In answer to your first question, yes, this type of IPC will work. Which line is actually generating the error, and what is the actual return value? How are you creating and starting the threads, and how do you synchronize opening the FIFO?

Comment: The "Open:  bad file descriptor" error is from the line "c = open(fifo_name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR);}" in the fifo_open program in C shown above.  According to the man page on open() (https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) it is considered successful if it returns a non-negative file descriptor, which it does, so I don't understand why I also get that message.

Comment: I create and start the threads with each thread pinned to a separate core using its affinity mask.  The thread creation is the same as with the single fd setup that works, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `open(2)` cannot return `EBADF`, only `openat(2)`. And if `c` is a positive number, then what you're seeing is a previous value of `errno` or something.

Comment: Then I'll assume the error message is an error, so that leaves the mystery of why the writer side returns zero bytes even though file descriptors were created successfully on both write and read sides.

Comment: Tidbit: do not use `access()`! This is intended for specialized setuid/setgid applications to find out if the *underlying* user would be able to access the file, it's absolutely not a handy-dandy "does the file exist?" function. Use `stat()` instead to check for existence.

Comment: Don't call `perror()` unconditionally; only call it if the return value indicates an error.  Similarly with `errno`; don't test it unless the function called indicates an error.

Comment: The `O_CREAT` flag doesn't seem to make sense.  With it, if the fifo you're trying to open doesn't exist, you'll create a regular file with the same name instead.  And moreover since you don't pass a third argument to `open()`, that file will get random permissions.

Comment: And why are you trying to open a fifo in `O_RDWR` mode?  What is that supposed to accomplish?  POSIX makes this "undefined behavior"; Linux allows it but the behavior is not likely to be what you want.

Comment: And as general advice: fix the indentation and brace placement.  As it stands it's hard to read; I don't know any common C formatting style where the closing brace of a block goes on the same line as its last statement.

Comment: @NateEldredge — it seems to be the preferred style for Pico.  I agree that it is very unconventional for C.

Answer (score 1):

> perror("open");

You cannot simply call perror() as it can return the previous error.
You have to check whether your syscall indeed generated an error. In case of open() you should do:

```
if (c < 0) {
   perror("open");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the communication is going to be between threads in a single process, you can use `pipe(2)` system call and give `fd[0]` to the reader thread while giving `fd[1]` to the writer.  You don't even need to `open()` or have a name in the filesytem associated to the fifo.  You still will need to close `fd[1]` if you want to signal end of file to the reader.